# How do I reset the STM32 HAL UART driver (HAL) state?

Tags: c, stm32, interrupt, hardware

I know one can enable a UART receive interrupt using

```c
HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&huart2, (uint8_t *)rx_buffer, expectedNumberOfBytes)
```

- But once started how does one stop it, "manually"?

We can disable the UART interrupt using `HAL_NVIC_DisableIRQ()` (ex: `HAL_NVIC_DisableIRQ(USART1_IRQn)`). This will prevent it from raising an interrupt, but the state set by the function `HAL_UART_Receive_IT` which is `HAL_UART_STATE_BUSY_RX` needs to be set back to `HAL_UART_STATE_READY` for the uart handle to go back to a state that can accept a new `HAL_UART_Receive_IT()` call.

**Question**
How do I reset the state of the UART interrupt if I wish to disable a Rx interrupt after some time?

Stack Overflow questions do not address how to reset the state; I have referred to these questions:

1. [Disabling interrupt in interrupt handler STM32F407](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34611870/disabling-interrupt-in-interrupt-handler-stm32f407)
2. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/100073/stm32-usart-rx-interrupts

I could use `USART_ClearITPendingBit()` or `USART_ITConfig()` but these are defined as private functions by STM's HAL library. So should I use them?

Comment: You should probably use clearer terminology.  `HAL_UART_Receive_IT` is a driver function, not an interrupt handler. It sets state for the receive driver. The UART peripheral has interrupt state of its own, but this is different from the state within the software driver, which seems to be what you are stuck on. So I think what you are asking is "How do I reset the STM32 HAL UART driver state?" If that's not what you mean, and you want to reset the peripheral (UART hardware) state, or you want to reset the interrupt handling (NVIC hardware) state, please edit your question to make that clear.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> How [do I] reset the state of the UART interrupt if [I] wish to disable a Rx interrupt after some time[?]

(See it's usage in "**stm32f4xx_hal_uart.c**", for example.)

The `huart->RxState` member of a uart handle struct is really only used internally by the HAL library when doing things such as `HAL_UART_Receive()`, `HAL_UART_Receive_IT()`, `HAL_UART_Receive_DMA()`, (and many other internal functions like this), etc. If you manually implement your own interrupt-based and ring-buffer-based UART Tx and Rx calls, however, *which is the preferred way to do it*, this member is completely meaningless and it doesn't matter what you do with it, as it is used only inside HAL library function calls and HAL ISR handlers (neither of which you have to use), and really has nothing to do with the register-level interrupts and things directly.

By digging around the source code in **stm32f4xx_hal_uart.c** (for example), however, here are a couple valid options you can use:

## 1. How to reset `huart->RxState` to `HAL_UART_STATE_READY`:

1. Call `HAL_UART_Init()`. By inspecting its source code, you'll see it calls `huart->RxState= HAL_UART_STATE_READY;` before returning.
2. Just manually set `huart->RxState = HAL_UART_STATE_READY;` So long as you know you have properly stopped the interrupt-based receive in the middle of its processing, this is perfectly valid.

Let's take this further, however.

Imagine you are using UART7 on an STM32F4. Therefore, in your **stm32f4xx_it.c** interrupt handler file, you'll see the following code auto-generated by STM32CubeMX:

```c
/**
* @brief This function handles UART7 global interrupt.
*/
void UART7_IRQHandler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN UART7_IRQn 0 */

  /* USER CODE END UART7_IRQn 0 */
  HAL_UART_IRQHandler(&huart7);
  /* USER CODE BEGIN UART7_IRQn 1 */

  /* USER CODE END UART7_IRQn 1 */
}
```

Let's go over some layers of disabling/enabling interrupts.

## 2. From broadest to narrowest scope, here are several ways to disable/enable the USART Rx interrupt:

1. You can disable/enable ALL interrupts, including this `UART7_IRQHandler()`, using these ARM-core CMSIS calls:

   ```
   __disable_irq();
   __enable_irq();
   ```

   Source: https://stm32f4-discovery.net/2015/06/how-to-properly-enabledisable-interrupts-in-arm-cortex-m/

   So, you could do the following to disable the interrupt, reset the `RxState`, and then start up the interrupt-based receive again when ready:

   ```
   __disable_irq();
   huart7->RxState= HAL_UART_STATE_READY;

   __enable_irq();
   HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&huart7, (uint8_t *)rx_buffer, expectedNumberOfBytes);
   ```
2. You can disable/enable ONLY the `UART7_IRQHandler()` interrupts (all 10 types of uart7 interrupts connected to this interrupt vector, including Tx-related, Rx-related, error-related, etc), using these STM32 HAL calls:

   ```
   HAL_NVIC_DisableIRQ(UART7_IRQn);
   HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(UART7_IRQn);
   ```

   Then, do the same as just above except use these calls to disable/enable the interrupts instead.
3. If you dig down into the implementation of `HAL_UART_IRQHandler()`, however, which is called by `UART7_IRQHandler()`, you'll see that it only calls the interrupt-based receive handler, `UART_Receive_IT()`, if both the `USART_SR_RXNE` bit ("Receive Not Empty", inside the USART Status Register) and the `USART_CR1_RXNEIE` bit ("Receive Not Empty Interrupt Enable", inside the USART Control Register 1), are *both* set. The `RXNE` bit is set whenever a byte comes in, and is cleared whenever you read the data register or write a zero to it. **The interrupt-enable bit is something you have full control over to disable this UART receive interrupt, and if you clear this bit manually, you will disable the receive interrupt withOUT disabling any other type of interrupt associated with this USART. This is the best way to do it, as there are 10 interrupt sources associated with this UART.** In other words, clearing this bit not only causes the check inside `HAL_UART_IRQHandler()` to fail, but it also prevents the receive interrupt from happening in the first place! Refer to the **Reference Manual RM0090 Rev 16**, for example:

   p969: [image]

   p1009: [image]

   p1011: [image]

   p1015: [image]

   p1013: [image]

   **So, to disable/enable the USART Receive Not Empty interrupt only, do the following.** Refer to the Control Register (USART_CR1) on p1013, shown just above.

   ```
   // Disable the USART Receive Not Empty interrupt
   CLEAR_BIT(huart7.Instance.CR1, USART_CR1_RXNEIE);

   // Enable the USART Receive Not Empty interrupt
   SET_BIT(huart7.Instance.CR1, USART_CR1_RXNEIE);
   ```

   Now, you could do the following to disable the USART Receive interrupt, reset the HAL RxState, and then start up the interrupt-based receive again when ready:

   ```
   CLEAR_BIT(huart7.Instance.CR1, USART_CR1_RXNEIE);
   huart7->RxState= HAL_UART_STATE_READY;

   SET_BIT(huart7.Instance.CR1, USART_CR1_RXNEIE); // This call isn't actually necessary, as this bit is set inside `HAL_UART_Receive_IT()` as well
   HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&huart7, (uint8_t *)rx_buffer, expectedNumberOfBytes);
   ```

## 3. How to (awkwardly) use `HAL_UART_Receive_IT()` for continual interrupt-based receiving.

TODO

## 4. Why `HAL_UART_Receive_IT()` really isn't a very useful function after-all.

TODO

## 5. How to manually configure your own interrupt-based UART Tx and Rx ISRs and functions.

TODO

Comment: I like the way you think.  IMO the HAL drivers are a clunky undocumented layer wrapping the well-documented hardware.  Whatever portability and reuse advantages might exist from using the vendor library are totally negated by lack of documentation and hidden interactions with peripherals other than the one the driver is supposed to be for.  You can't hope to understand and use the HAL layer without thoroughly reading the manual for the register-level interface, and once you do that you no longer need the HAL.

Comment: Woah! Thank you for taking the time to answer. So, as you said, `Status` is just a `HAL flag` and doesn't do much w.r.t the hardware. I'll check out your suggestion 2 and get back. And please do write 3,4 and 5 when you get the time. Thanks again.

Comment: @BenVoigt, yeah there's definitely a lot of truth to what you're saying. The HAL layer can be helpful, but it could be much better I think, and you are absolutely right about having to dig and dig and dig to understand what it's really doing. Even knowing just *how to properly use it* requires looking at example code, then *also* reading the STM32 Reference Manuals and scouring through the HAL source code, as its usage and structure isn't very well documented, unfortunately.

Comment: Waitung for those TODOS ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `HAL_UART_Abort_IT`.

Comment: Hi. Can you expand on your answer please?

Answer (score 0):

Most UARTs clear any pending Receive interrupt when the program reads from the holding register. So my answer would be: simply read the data register after disabling interrupts, and ignore the result.

I haven't had a chance to try this on my STM32 yet, but...

Comment: How do I read from the data register? In the fn `HAL_UART_Receive` data is read from `huart->Instance->DR`. So I tried reading from it. But `huart->State` won't be reset by anyone/anything, I had to manually reset it. Is this the right approach? (It works, as in, the next Rx_interrupt works as expected.)

Comment: Updating the `huart->State` variable manually sounds like a pain, but the alternative would be worse. If you read the Data Register *before* you disabled interrupts, then the `State` variable would (probably) be updated - but a new character *could* arrive before the disable happened, which would put you back in the original state.

Answer (score 0):

There is a function `static void UART_EndRxTransfer(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart)`
in the HAL library that does the following:

- Disable RXNE, PE and ERR interrupts
- restore `huart->RxState` to Ready

I found that function in the `stm32f7xx_hal_uart.c` file. However, it is defined as `static`, so I just copied over the definition into the file where I used it. It might be a bit hacky but it worked for me.